# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError - Rails app + Swift 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, swift2, imagemagick, paperclip

I am trying to upload a photo from a Swift 2 application, and I am getting Bad Request.

I am using:

- Amazon EC2
- Ruby on Rails
- Paperclip

I am executing this code:

### Swift

```
func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
   let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
   let base64Encoded = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
   return base64Encoded
}
```

and then I send the info through a parameter:

```
let image_str = self.global.convertImageToBase64(self.global.compressForUpload(self.newMediaImage.image!, withHeightLimit:750, andWidthLimit:750))

parameters["spot[image]"] = "data:image/png;base64,\(image_str)"
```

notice that my headers are:

```
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data"
headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"] = "POST"
headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With"
```

And I get this message error:

```
I, [2016-01-07T10:11:41.148123 #4490]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/8d777f385d3dfec8815d20f7496026dc20160107-4490-m5y4d3[0]' 2>/dev/null
I, [2016-01-07T10:11:41.152860 #4490]  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I, [2016-01-07T10:11:41.153061 #4490]  INFO -- : Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/8d777f385d3dfec8815d20f7496026dc20160107-4490-m5y4d3[0]' 2>/dev/null
I, [2016-01-07T10:11:41.157503 #4490]  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I, [2016-01-07T10:11:41.544868 #4490]  INFO -- : [AWS S3 400 0.378927 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"api",:key=>"spots/images//original/data.") AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest

I, [2016-01-07T10:11:41.917895 #4490]  INFO -- : [AWS S3 400 0.372396 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"api",:key=>"spots/images//medium/data.") AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest

I, [2016-01-07T10:11:42.293064 #4490]  INFO -- : [AWS S3 400 0.374527 0 retries] head_object(:bucket_name=>"api",:key=>"spots/images//thumb/data.") AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest AWS::S3::Errors::BadRequest
```

**A piece of the image that my rails app receive would be:**

```
lN c32Ov1f9nesG/5nVgRpMz wHT1CrwVQ3dM x3tff cnU xpMdWV9MpX1m5Vi\r\n/VvXv3VdB55EHajBVFfUJ1FRayjVfWt1HXg daAGUw2mGkx1HajrQF0HHlUdeB5g\r\nqvtUHlWlq998H9Gbb/N/o3m7brDr/85PqAPPA0w/4cHWje8janzr379uXOs68KTq\r\nQA2musI qQpbA78Gfl0Hfv06UIOpBlMNpp9VB56q2 yp3vfP p3rz713G/M0wFT/\r\nEe79w9Zvlb/ W2X9G9e/8a9aB54GmOo3jhpMdR2o60BdB55NHajBVFf2Z1PZf9W3\r\ny/S9ql6Far6u399ev vn e3P8J71sAbTPR/YL9241c/ih/8B6/pUu PqOvDvdaAG\r\nU90Y141xXQfqOlDXgUdVB2ow1RXyUVXI u3x398ev mZ1G6oun4/wTauBtMT/NG \r\nqaGqv2/dUNV1oK4Dj7wO1GB65D9QDaEHVhD17103ynUdePR1oAZTXUkffSWt4VzD\r\nua4Dz6sO1GCqwVSDqa4DdR2o68CjqgM1mOoK agqZP1m/LzejOvfu/69b6oDNZhq\r\nMNVgsg7U0Wt1PajbgkdTB2ow1ZXx0VTGm96c6rL6jbquA8 vDtRgqsFUg6muA3Ud\r\nqOvAo6oDNZiee4WsXViP6g/5IOrA37T XX/871o/8wd75jWYnjuY6u//YH mB4FK\r\n/XvUv0ddB17UYKorQd0Q1HWgrgN1HXhUdaAGU10hH1WFrFXH8 vorn/z jdvrgM1\r\nmGow1WCq60BdB o68KjqQA2mukI qgrZ/OZUb9dv03UdeH51oAZTDaYaTHUdqOtA\r\nXQceVR2owVRXyEdVIeu34 f3dlz/5vVv3lwHajDVYKrBVNeBug7UdeBR1YEaTHWF\r\nfFQVsvnNqd6u36brOvD86kANphpMNZjqOlDXgboOPKo6UIOprpCPqkLWb8fP7 24\r\n/s3r37y5DtRgqsFUg6muA3UdqOvAo6oDNZjqCvmoKmTzm1O9fYe36Xry0LoO/2Lt\r\nWA2mX wHrRvyOzTk9W9eN R1HXjUdaAGU11BH3UFrUFbg7auA8 vDtRgqsFUg lX\r\nrQO1i6 u20 0bn/6/135Eixq4JAOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Comment: I think I might know the issue. There are spaces on my image string that should be "+". Does anyone know how to encode + characters before submit the params? I searched on the internet but couldn't find anything about "+"

Comment: Do you have image magick installed on EC2 and Rmagick gem included?

Comment: @KaranPurohit Yes, I do. "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version.
libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded."

Comment: Have you tried setting  `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/path/to/identify" ` in your application.rb ?

Comment: @KaranPurohit I just did what you recommended and I am still getting the error. Noticed that I typed which identify on my server to get the right path and did it.

Comment: try running `identify -format '%wx%h,1' 'anyfile.jpg' ` on server and see what you get

Comment: @KaranPurohit ubuntu@ip-172-...:~$ identify -format '%wx%h,1' 'anyfile.jpg' 
identify.im6: unable to open image `anyfile.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.

Comment: I also tried to do it as a png which is the format that I am trying to upload...   identify.im6: unable to open image `anyfile.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
identify.im6: unable to open file `anyfile.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3667.

Comment: @KaranPurohit I just deployed the app on heroku and it is working there :( but I need to make it happen on my amazon ec2 server

Comment: Try uninstalling and then reinstalling imagemagick on EC2, I ran into such situation before.

Comment: @KaranPurohit I tried it in different ways and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. The solution was:

I just changed the version of the aws-sdk gem which was < 2 to 
`gem 'aws-sdk', '>= 2.0.0'` and it worked pretty well.

Besides that, I re-installed imagemagick on amazon ec2 and Rmagick.